Is it haram to make anime fact channel in islam?
I have anime youtube and i post anime(only demon slayer) related facts and i don't use music i don't add female character in my video i don't use bad words in my video.Means i don't use anything that disrespect islam.Can i still make the video related to anime?can i make the video using anime clips? Can i earn money using this channel?
I repeat i make just fact about demon slayer anime.Plz give me answer.
